# MVC 4 - Save Row information back to the Database when a user has edited a field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, editorfor

I am using an editorfor template so that users can edit row information inline when the information is displayed as a table. The user then has a save button below the table which when pressed sends the whole Model to a HttpPost method which then iterates over each row and saves the row back to the database. As you can imagine this can become quite slow when the row number increases as it has to iterate over every row then save the information to the database.

I was looking for some way of saving a single row back to the database if a field is edited within that row or maybe setting a flag to true which when the user presses the save button it only iterates over the rows that have been edited and only saves those rows back to the database?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Jay

Comment: Have u tried the code.We are here to solve the problem.you have to try your self if you face any problem then we can solve it.

Comment: Did you actually measure the performance and detected a problem? Do you want to fix the issue on the client side (ie., only send changed rows) and/or on the server side (ie. only update changed rows). Do you update each row in a separate transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't use Ajax to update each row?

You can associate the button to a javascript (jquery) function responsible to update (post) the modified row.

In this way you only update the modified row.

To avoid problems you can use a curtain or a spinner during the execution of the update.

Regards,
André